# Are there other repeating cycles of terms in this hailstone-like sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been experimenting with a hailstone-like sequence where if a term is a multiple of 2, the next term is one half the previous term and if a term is not a multiple of two, the next term is the previous term multiplied by 3 and one higher.
I have noticed that there are at least three cycles of repeating terms that can occur, with the minimum terms being 1, 5, and 17, respectively. Are there any other repeating cycles?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: This is 3n-1, not 3n+1.

Comment: sorry, I should have said that in the question.